# Vertical Arrow in UITabBarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating tab bar controller In other view controller. I want to add vertical arrow on TabBar . I used IdevRecipes from github but it is showing exception..Here is my code to add tabbarcontroller.

```
DropboxHomeViewController *homeView = [[DropboxHomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DropboxHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
homeView.title=@"More";

UINavigationController *homeNavigation = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeView]autorelease ];


//tab bar initalization
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] ;

//number of tabs in tabbar controller
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tourNavigation,mapNavigation ,browserNavigation, dropboxNavigation,homeNavigation,nil];
tabBarController.selectedViewController = tourNavigation;
tabBarController.delegate  =self;

//flip animation
tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;       

[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

How can I add arrow in this code.

code to add arrow Image

```
- (void) addTabBarArrow
{
  UIImage* tabBarArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarNipple.png"];
  self.tabBarArrow = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tabBarArrowImage] autorelease];
  // To get the vertical location we start at the bottom of the window, go up by height of the tab bar, go up again by the height of arrow and then come back down 2 pixels so the arrow is slightly on top of the tab bar.
  CGFloat verticalLocation = self.window.frame.size.height - tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height - tabBarArrowImage.size.height + 2;
  tabBarArrow.frame = CGRectMake([self horizontalLocationFor:0], verticalLocation, tabBarArrowImage.size.width, tabBarArrowImage.size.height);

  [self.window addSubview:tabBarArrow];
}
```

Comment: You are saying exception. Can you post the crash logs?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan -1.5]'

Comment: Can you post the animation code? And please format the code.

Comment: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes  I am using this example..It is creating for tabbarapplication and I am creating tab bar controller in other view

Comment: So that's working. Are you using the same code?

Comment: Ya that's working, I am using that same code but changes self.window.frame.size  to self.view.frame.size

Comment: self.window -> self.view seems right. So the crash occurs when you do that?

Comment: If I use self.window it will give error then I changed self.view and it is giving exception

Comment: return (tabIndex * tabItemWidth) + halfTabItemWidth;  exception occurs after this line

Comment: It's hard to tell with info at hand but you might have better luck logging all the parameters to the `CGRectMake`.

Comment: Actually I am trying to design my app .. I saw lots of apps has attractive designs thats why I am using that..Can you suggest other way.. how can I make my app attractive..I am new in iphone developer

Answer (score 0):

In the viewController where you want the arrow, use

```
[[self tabBarItem] setTitle:@"Up Arrow"];
[[self tabBarItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uparrow.png"]];
```

Of course, you first need to make/find an image and then add it to your project.

Comment: It will move automatically?I mean like Twtiee app

Comment: No, it's an image, not an animation. What kind of movement are you trying to achieve?

Comment: (A) I have no idea what this means having never seen the app you mentioned. (B) You should update your question with more details about what you're after.